# Saving user meta as single values or an array

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a plugin which is going to save about 10 custom user meta for certain users bound to the plugin. Among these metas we find: Address, zip, occupation, etc...

These metas will only be used by the plugin, and mostly (if not always) all of them will be fetched from the DB together to be shown in a table view in the admin.

So, I'm thinking about the best way to save these values.

I could do this:

```
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'address', 'kings street 45');
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'zip', '12345');
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'occupation', 'nurse');
... some more meta
```

Or would it be better to do this:

```
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'plugin_name_user_meta', array(
    'address' => 'kings street 45'
    'zip' => '12345'
    'occupation' => 'nurse')
    ... some more meta
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the first answer and I would use your first suggestion.

Why? Because if you use `add_user_meta` for each field you have a seperate field in the database for each value. That means:

1) You can do **meta and Wildcard Queries** e.g. "*Select all user with a ZIP starting with 11*". This is impossible if you save an array especially as the array will be saved in serialized format.

***Keep this possibility open!*** Some day you may want to do complicated queries on this data even if it is not the case currently.

Have a look at the WP Meta Query class and even better the WP User Query class:

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

2) You do not have a disadvantage in extensibility: As these fields are already saved in a meta table and not within fixed columns you can add and remove values dynamically.

However @Juan is right with the hint on prefixes: You definitly should prefix your meta_values in order to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 4):

In WordPress I prefer to work with arrays because in helps keeping my data organized, so I would go the second way. Nevertheless, if you go the first way, prefix all the `meta`s with a unique ID related to your plugin.